# What is the difference between outer measure and inner measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> What is the difference between outer measure and inner measure ?

From the definition, the outer measure must be bigger, but under which conditions are they equal, for example for measurable $A$ and any $B\supset A$, does it always follow that;

$$m^*(B\cap A)=m(A)$$

or Is there an equation, for these 2 measures ?

I have 2 Examples

> $1.$ If $m(A)=0$, show that for any $B$
>
> $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(B\setminus A)=m^*(B)$

Author's solution:

$m^*(B)\le m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(B\setminus A)+m^*(A)\le m^*(B)+m^*(A)\overset?=m^*(B)$

(So $m(A)=0\Rightarrow m^*(A)=0$, but in general the converse of this implication is true.)

> $2.$ Show if $A$ is measurable and a set of finite measure and $B\supset A$
>
> $m^*(B\setminus A)=m^*(B)-m(A)$

Author's solution:

Carathéodory-criterion implies;

$m^*(B)=m^*(B\cap A)+m^*(B\setminus A)\overset?=m(A)+m^*(B\setminus A)$

(He assumed $m^*(B\cap A)=m(A)$, but why ?)

Comment: If $A\subset B$ then $A\cap B=A$, and so clearly $m^\star(A)=m^\star(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 2):

The outer measure is monotonic, and $A \subset B \implies A= B \cap A$, and therefore:
$$m^{*}(B \cap A) = m^{*}(A)$$
Since $A$ is measurable, $m(A)=m^{*}(A)$, and finally: 
$$m^{*}(B \cap A) = m(A)$$

Comment: Mostly-unrelated question: is there any specific meaning to $m^*$ as opposed to $m$?

Comment: @SubSevn $m^*$ denotes outer measure, which is defined for all subsets of whatever set we are working in, whereas $m$ denotes measure, which is defined only for those subsets which are measurable, meaning that they satisfy the Caratheodory criterion. For a measurable set $A$, we have $m(A) = m^*(A)$ by definition. For a nonmeasurable set, $m(A)$ is not defined. The key difference between $m^*$ and $m$ is that $m$ is countably additive, whereas $m^*$ need not be, although it is countably subadditive.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks - I was under the assumption that $\mu$ and $\varphi$ was the usual notation, I hadn't seen $m$ before.